# Convert Windows 8.1 project to Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 C# project for windows store ready.
I want to make a copy of it for Windows Phone 8.

Is there any good and easy way to do this?

I use Visual Studio Ultimate (2012 and 2013).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple/automatic way to do it, but the code will be mostly compatible. The UI will probably need to be adjusted significantly.

If you target Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT you will find more of the code will work (Windows Phone 8.0 does not support WinRT, which is what Windows Store 8.1 apps use).

A possibly better way would be to create a new Universal Windows 8.1 WinRT project and copy your existing project code in, placing as much as possible in the shared project (or in class libraries), then create a new UI for the phone version (you can keep most of the actual code behind in the shared project - see my blog post here: http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=760 - to minimise duplication. Note that this must target WP8.1, not 8.0.

If you absolutely must target WP8.0 then you may have no better option than to just copy in the code and adjust it where necessary. This will be relatively easy for a simple app, but relatively messy for a complex app that happens to use APIs that don't match up.

Comment: ok thanks! I'll probably try copying XAML and try to fix any possible errors... TY again ;)

Comment: I know but I need to make it for windows phone 8 for a competition ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, they are different platforms, so you'll still have to adjust your code for that, but maybe converting your portable code to a portable class library will help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yeah, I wasn't very specific at my question. :S
I don't really have problem with the code...
My biggest problem is the design of the app. I want to copy the excact same design to the phone 8 app.

Comment: You can copy the XAML directly across just like the code behind, but it may not suit a phone, and some things may not work unless you target WP8.1. For example most phone apps should be portrait, most Windows Store apps are landscape.